# How to import specific column from an excel sheet and store its values in a variable array in python?

Tags: python

I would like to import four columns from an excel sheet into python and store them as different arrays.

I have tried using 'pandas' module, but couldn't get how to achieve my requirement properly.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx","Sheet4")
    tg1f = df['A']
```

I expect to store the values of different columns in separate arrays. For example, the values from the 1st column of the excel sheet should be stored in  a variable named 'Temperature'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_excel` expects the column names to be in the first row of the sheet. If you have no header in your sheet and want to extract the first column, you should do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx","Sheet4", header=None)
tg1f = df.iloc[:, 0]                       # extract column by numeric position
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet4")

targets = {}

for index, colName in enumerate(df.columns):
    if index > 3:
        break
    targets[col] = df[colName]
```

You should be aware that the assignment `tg1f = df['A']` will actually return a Pandas Series datatype, since Pandas DataFrames are essentially a concatenation of Series Values aligned on indices.  Series are akin to Lists, with the ability to store additional metadata (like indices).

If you truly wanted to store the columns as lists, you could cast them like this:

```
for index, colName in enumerate(df.columns):
    if index > 3:
        break
    targets[col] = list(df[colName])
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped.